# OpenCV real-time stream very slow with pixel manipulation

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a script to manipulate video from a webcam. I am trying to do this through OpenCV with Python, but I am running into some issues.

If I run the video capture stream with no pixel manipulation applied, the stream works fine and has a smooth frame rate. However, I applied a threshold loop as a test, and my stream undergoes major lag and updates once every few seconds. Any ideas if it is possible to optimise this? Ideally, I am looking to get a 30 fps stream with the video manipulation applied. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
T = 100

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height, width, channels = frame.shape

    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if frame[y,x,0] < T:
                frame[y,x]=0
            else:
               frame[y,x]=255

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

accessing Pixel by pixel in image processing in general is very bad practice as it slow the performance very much, packages like opencv and numpy has optimized this by doing matrix operations allowing your program to be much more faster, here is a sample code that will perform your task but much more faster.

import cv2
import numpy as np

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
T = 100

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height, width, channels = frame.shape
    B,G,R = cv2.split(frame)    
#     for x in range(width):
#         for y in range(height):
#             if frame[y,x,0] < T:
#                 frame[y,x]=0
#             else:
#                 frame[y,x]=255
    
    _,B = cv2.threshold(B,T,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    frame = cv2.merge((B,G,R))

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Yea I've seen that, I'm just interested in manipulating the processing matrices myself rather than using the built-in functions like .threshold. And also, aren't the OpenCV functions processing the video pixel by pixel anyways?

Comment: Looking at the source code: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp it seems to be pixel by pixel as well?

Comment: @WassiliKorobitsyn The OpenCV source code is largely very highly optimised SIMD instructions, or failing that, highly optimised C++ and therefore many hundreds or thousands of times faster than interpreted Python.

Comment: By the way, there is no absolute need to split the image and recombine afterwards. i.e. `cv2.split()` followed by `cv2.merge()`. You could do it *"in-situ"* with `_,im[...,0] = cv2.threshold(im[...,0],T,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`